# Facebook "Access your information" via an api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to access data which is normally available to download from "Access your information" page? I am more interested in data of *Apps and Websites off of facebook* and *Ads information*. But would love to know if other contents is mapped to any api?

[image: Access your information page]

Comment: No it is not available in the API.

Comment: So there is no way other than manually downloading it? Is there any api which may provide same data?

Comment: Yes the user need to manually download it.

Comment: Could you add this comment as a a reply so that i can accept it as an answer.